# angular mat radio group select index

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, radio-button

I have a radio button in a mat radio group coming from a loop , the button and card should be colored based on the selected index,  but as you can see on the screenshot the radio button is selected but not colored in white

[image]

The radio button based on the selected index or selected radio should be like this but currently my logic does not work. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Any idea guys ? Thanks.

#html code

```
<p fxLayoutAlign="center" class="select-date-time-text">Select Available Date</p>
                <mat-radio-group>
                  <mat-card style="cursor: pointer;" [ngClass]="selectedIndex === i ? 'selected-schedule-card' : ''" *ngFor="let item of schedules;let i = index;" fxLayoutAlign="start center" style="cursor: pointer;margin-bottom: 20px;">
                    <mat-radio-button  color="accent"   [ngClass]="selectedIndex === i ? 'selected-schedule-radio' : ''"   value="i"  (click)="onSelect(item , i)">
                        <mat-icon class="date-icon" style="margin-top:3px;margin-left:10px;">today</mat-icon> {{item.proposedDateStartString}}
                      </mat-radio-button>
                  </mat-card>
              </mat-radio-group>
```

#tscode

```
    onSelect(item:any , index:number) {
    this.selectedIndex = index;
    this.selectedItem = item;
  }
```

#css

```
.selected-schedule-radio {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  
  .selected-schedule-card {
    background-color: #007DFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `change` event for this. Create a scope variable in your TS to hold the value, like

```
this.selectedDate='';
```

Put an`ngmodel` binding on the `mat-radio-group` element.

```
[ngModel]="selectedDate"
```

That will track the selected value of the whole radio group. Then make your `ngClass` compare the radio's value with the selectedValue

```
[ngClass]="selectedDate === item.proposedDateStartString ? 'selected-schedule-radio' : ''"
```

All together...

```
<mat-radio-group [ngModel]="selectedDate">
  <mat-card style="cursor: pointer;" [ngClass]="selectedIndex === i ? 'selected-schedule-card' : ''" *ngFor="let item of schedules;let i = index;" fxLayoutAlign="start center" style="cursor: pointer;margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <mat-radio-button color="accent" [ngClass]="selectedDate === item.proposedDateStartString ? 'selected-schedule-radio' : ''" >
      <mat-icon class="date-icon" style="margin-top:3px;margin-left:10px;">today</mat-icon> {{item.proposedDateStartString}}
    </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-card>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: I forgot to add, you need to set the value of your radio buttons - for each radio you would add `[value]=item.proposedDateStartString`

Answer (score 0):

Make a function on the ts side and use this on your html: (click)=“onSelect(item)”

Comment: Just add that after your ngfor on the matcard

Comment: I have updated my question and code Sir , can you please check ?